# How to change sytanx coloring for jquery selectors in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

i want to change jquery selector syntax coloring from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

but doesn't know where should i apply this change in color scheme setting of intellij idea, i checked all settings of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA auto-injects CSS in JQuery calls, so `"#input"` is highlighted according to **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | CSS | Id selector** preferences (just as @Rishikesh Sharat mentioned in his answer).
A hint: to find color settings for current element, put cursor on it, then in **Help | Find action...** enter **Jump to colors and fonts**. You can check what shortcut is assigned to this action in **Settings | Keymap | Other**

Comment: could you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756000/how-to-configure-intellij-idea-to-use-hibernate-persistence-tools-and-reading-ma

Answer (score 2):

In this case "#input" is a CSS selector. So, to change its foreground color, go to Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> CSS -> id selector, and then change the "id selector" foreground color to your desired choice. It's much easier to just search for "id selector" in settings, you'll find it in the CSS tab.